# What is a good measure of strength of a link and influence of a node?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, graph, social-networking

In the context of social networks, what is a good measure of strength of a link between two nodes? I am currently thinking that the following should give me what I want:

For two nodes A and B:
`Strength(A,B) = (neighbors(A) intersection neighbors(B))/neighbors(A)`

where neighbors(X) gives the total number of nodes directly connected to X and the intersection operation above gives the number of nodes that are connected to both A and B.

Of course, `Strength(A,B) != Strength(B,A)`.

Now knowing this, is there a good way to determine the influence of a node? I was initially using the [Degree Centrality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality#Degree_centrality) of a node to determine its "influence" but I somehow think its not a good idea because just because a node has a lot of outgoing links does not mean anything. Those links should be powerful as well. In that case, maybe using an aggregate of the strengths of each node connected to this node is a good idea to estimate its influence? Am I in the right direction? Does anyone have any suggestions?

**My Philosophy (and understanding of the terms):**

- Strength indicates how far A is
  willing to do what B has already done
- Influence indicates how far A can make B do something (persuasion perhaps?)

**Constraints:**
Access to only a subgraph. I mean, I am trying to be realistic here because social networks are huge and having a complete view is not so practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to check out some more sophisticated notions of distance.
A really cool one is "resistance distance", which lets you view distance as how likely a random path from one node will lead you to another

there are several days of lecture notes plus references to further reading at http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/462/.

Comment: Thanks. Some of them get into Electric Networks but I guess everything is the same :) Will go through them and get back.

Comment: np, you should get around to choosing an answer to accept if theres any good ones btw :)

Answer (score 1):

Few thoughts on this:

When you talk about influence of a node in a graph one centrality measurement that comes to mind it closeness centrality. Closeness centrality looks at the number of shortest paths in a graph the node is on. From an influence point of view, the node that is on the most shortest paths is the node that can share information the easiest, ie its nearer to more nodes than any other.

You also mention using the strengths of each node connected to a node. Maybe you should look at eigenvector centrality which ranks a node highly if its connected to other high degree nodes. This is an undirected version of PageRank.

Some questions that might affect you choice here are:

1. Is you graph directed?
2. Do you edges have weight? You mention strength... do you mean weights of some kind?

If you do have weights maybe the next step from a simple degree centrality would be to try a weighted degree centrality approach. Thus, just having a high number of connections doesn't automatically make you the most influential.

Comment: +1 for your thoughts and time. I was a little hesitant about closeness centrality because I am working on a subgraph (sorry! just updated me question). This means that Eigen Vector centrality is out of the picture (I remember that this measure requires a global view of the graph). The graph is undirected (thanks to social networks but maybe I should look at a way to turn it into a directed graph because I am trying to see the influence of one node on its friends when establishing friendships). As far as edge weights are concerned, I am still battling as to which one works best.

Comment: No probs. Interesting question regarding how to weight an isFriendsWith edge. Have you considered (have access) to how long they have been friends? Maybe this might help indicate a strength of friendship.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I've considered that. The only problem is not all social networks give out this information. For instance, take Facebook or Orkut, there's no easy way to figure out when two people established this friendship. One other metric I was thinking was the communication that took place but that isn't available easily either :)

Comment: Agreed. What other attributes do you have access to? Things like facebook tagging, messaging etc might help formulate some other approaches.

Comment: As a starting point, I am looking at LiveJournal and Facebook but lets just take Facebook to begin with. I am really paranoid about considering any other features except the connectivity because Facebook can "ruthlessly" limit access to them :) I was using some smart metrics from wall posts until a few months back when FB decided to limit access to walls...